# How to delete a line if a string is present in the line twice

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to delete all the lines which contains a string twice in the same line.

Example:

```
hi 
hi hello
hi hello hey
hey hi:hello:hi #delete this line
```

Result: As the last line contains "hi" twice. String is not separated properly by any fixed separator ,sometimes it is space or comma or colon or could be anything.

```
hi 
hi hello
hi hello hey
```

If it would be fixed column based data, I could have used:(rough idea)

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~/hi/) c++ ;if(c<2) print $0}'
```

Comment: Why isn't the second line deleted? It contains the string `h` twice. And `l` twice. The third line contains the string `he` twice, too.

Comment: @monk, I have posted solution which will have field separators as ` :#` in case you have more field separators then you could mention them too in code.

Comment: @jeremysprofile see a one-liner below.

Comment: @karakfa, I concede =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might be easier with `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/(\b\w+\b).*\b\1\b/d' file
```

if a word repeats delete the line.  You have to define the word with word boundaries otherwise any repeated character will match the regex.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I am using space delimited words.

Comment: space is a word boundary as well.  Did you try with the sample you posted above?  Perhaps your `sed` doesn't support back references.

Comment: @karakfa or may be their sed implementation doesn't support word boundaries.. I know GNU sed supports it, but not sure about other versions

Comment: also, you need another word boundary after `\1` or words like `hi` and `him` will match.. you could also use grep for better speed.. `grep -vE '(\b\w+\b).*\1\b'`

Comment: @Sundeep, right boundaries are not part of capture, need to be added to backreference as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[ :#]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(++a[$i]>1){delete a;next}};delete a} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
hi
hi hello
hi hello hey
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
awk -F'[ :;,]' '{ delete seen; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {seen[$i]++} # parse words and store in a hash             
       for(i in seen) if(seen[i] == 2) {next}                    # skip line if it has a word that is repeated two times
     }1' file
```

Comment: I think I beat you with 8 or 9 secs :) we both have followed same approach only thing is I have taken some more field separators since OP told it may have few different ones. I leave up to OP for decision, cheers buddy.